# asp net core - how to validate field uniqueness

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model, unique

I have a unique field in the database table. When inserting/updating data, I can easily validate uniquness of the data in the controller:

```
if (db.Country.Where(x => x.ID != m.ID && x.Name == m.Name).Count() > 0)
{
   // take action
}
```

But I think it'd be better to incorporate this check in the model, by using IValidatableObject interface:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext);
```

However, here I don't have access to the database context, which I need to check for the field uniqueness...?

Comment: I don't think data annotation or Validation possibilities work here, as uniqueness is dbs work. You'd need all tuples from the corresponding table there, which will result in another db call whenever you set this property, if you implement it this way. I think the easiest way is to get the relevant values into memory before validating, and then call the procedure on the list.

Comment: So after all, you mean this should be the controller's job?

Answer (score 0):

Your model ideally shouldn't know about your database as this tends to mix separation of concerns and can make it more difficult to test. It can be done however:

```cs
public class Country : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dbContext = (YourDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(YourDbContext));
        if (dbContext.Country.Any(c => c.ID != ID && c.Name == Name))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The name must be unique.", new[] { nameof(Name) });
        }
    }
}
```

The other option is to create a custom attribute that can check for uniqueness:

```cs
public class UniqueCountryNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dbContext = (YourDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(YourDbContext));
        if (dbContext.Country.Any(c => c.ID != ((Country)validationContext.ObjectInstance).ID && c.Name == (string)value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The name must be unique.");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [UniqueCountryName]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you mentioned in your comment, this check can also be done in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Country country)
{
    var dbContext = new YourDbContext();
    if (dbContext.Country.Any(c => c.ID != country.ID && c.Name == country.Name))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(country.Name), "The name must be unique.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    dbContext.Country.Add(country);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(country);
}
```

If your validation logic on your models becomes complex, it might make sense to use the FluentValidation package. I'm including it as an option as it is a popular package and what I tend to use:

```cs
public class CountryValidator : AbstractValidator<Country>
{
    public CountryValidator(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("The name is required.")
            .MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("The name cannot exceed 100 characters.")
            .Must((country, name) => IsNameUnique(dbContext, country.ID, name))
                .WithMessage("The name must be unique.");
    }

    private bool IsNameUnique(YourDbContext dbContext, int countryId, string name)
    {
        return !dbContext.Country.Any(c => c.ID != countryId && c.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Whichever option you choose depends on your use case, however I would not recommend the first option of using IValidatableObject since the custom ValidationAttribute achieves the same result in a cleaner way.